# Android, how i can to change inten in onClick function?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

So I use  a simple [navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

```
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

public PlanetFragment() {
    // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}
private View RootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
    RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);


    if(i == 0)
    {
        RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
         ImageButton login = (ImageButton)RootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
         login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
               RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
            }
         });
    }
    if(i == 1)
    {
        RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
    }
    if(i == 3)
    {
        RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
    }

    return RootView;
}
```

}

So, simply if i click on first element on my navigation - it's work, and than i see screen with button. If i want to click on this button i need to change intent.

So this code must do it:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a good practice to use variable names that start with a lower-case character. e.g. `rootView` instead of `RootView`.

Comment: This is not the right way of doing it. Whenever you need to open new activities - Android recommends using Intents. The [official tutorial here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) should help you.

Comment: but if i will use activities i can't use sidebar. Yes?

Comment: use multiple fragments instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not understanding `Fragments`. Your sentence:

```
RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
```

It's only creating a generic view, but that's not the same as a `Fragment`. What you need to do is create a new `Fragment` class and then change your `OnClick` method to something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentTransaction myTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    myTransaction.replace(R.id.your_fragment_container, new YourNewFragment());
    myTransaction.commit();
}
```

That will replace the current `Fragment` for the one you are trying to show.

Comment: but here  `myTransaction.replace(R.id.your_fragment_container, new YourNewFragment());`
my fragment container is current xml layout?

Comment: Yes. A `Fragment` runs on top of an `Activity`, as well as any other `Fragment` that is added to the stack. So in your MainActivity xml you need to add a container, somewhere in where your 'Fragment' will be added. Other wise the `Activity` doesn't know where to place the `Fragment`. Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) for more guidance